# form not submitting on magento 1.9.0.1, giving 404 error page on submit

Tags: magento, contact-form

I created a CMS page with name Contact and used this code in it:

```
{{block type='core/template' name='contactForm' template='contacts/form.phtml'}}
```

https://www.peterwynnscore.com.au/contact/
the page showing the contact form but when I submit, it just refresh the page and do nothing. I checked the form action and it was blank, so I edited my `"/contacts/form.phtml"` file and add this in action `"/contacts/index/post"`, but it gives `404 error` page when I submit the form. what can be the issue here?

I checked my error log `"var/log/system.log"`and it gives me this `error:
ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153`

I have no clue what is wrong with the form action URL. any help is very much appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `form action` in it. Add `form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post"` like

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

and then try.

Comment: i added the form action inside the form.phtml file directly. its a same thing, yes?

Comment: Try action with full store url.